# how to open an excel file in MAC from network location or shared folder using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am using excel 2016 VBA both in PC and MAC. I know how to open files from local drive and I can also open files in pc from network location but I can not open files from MAC.

suppose my file location is: "\10.183.3.110\crm\LOG_Do_not_open\LOG.xlsx"

My code for windows is:

> filename1 = "\\10.183.3.110\crm\LOG_Do_not_open\LOG.xlsx"
>
> Workbooks.Open fileName:=filename1

for MAC my code is:

> filename1 = "//10.183.3.110/crm/LOG_Do_not_open/LOG.xlsx"
>
> Workbooks.Open fileName:=filename1

My code for windows is working fine but MAC can not open the file.
What is the right code for MAC to open the file?

Comment: Is there any error that you get ?

Comment: have you tried using the `:` path separator instead? forward slash is for web addresses.

Comment: It just shows an error like: "excel did not find this file"

Comment: Finally I used the method to get file name automatically using getopenfilename() method.

Comment: Finally I used the method to get file name automatically using getopenfilename() method.

When I select the file to open, it returned the following result:
fileName1 = "/Volumes/crm/LOG_Do_not_open/LOG.xlsx"
and successfully opened the file.

then I removed the getopenfilename() method and assigned the above path string and amazingly it opened the file without any problem.

Now, I am confused how can I open a file from a network location, without using the IP address or computer name.
Is this applicable when I am connected with several network PC?